# Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade to ubuntu 13.04 stalled

Tags: installation, upgrade, 13.04, internet, update-manager

My update manager and error report programs were broken in Ubuntu 12.04, so i decided to remove 12.04 altogether and upgrade to 13.04. The error I am Getting is:

```
(process:8276): GLib_CRITICAL **:g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

The Internet at my house is unstable. So after several hours of something "installing", the Internet had to be reconnected. After a while longer, I opened up Ubuntu help, here, and the error showed up. The time count when I opened up the Internet was at about 14 hours into "installation."

I have no idea what to do.

PS. I am downloading from a disk, not update manager.

Solved: I quit the upgrade, then opened ubuntu as a temporary os, copied the home folder off, most of the files anyway, and completely reinstalled. Works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download ubuntu 13.04 from the website. Boot it from a bootable usb or dvd. Install ubuntu 13.04 by choosing something else in the install option. This would help you to manage the partition and install 13.04. If you have a slow internet connection then skip the update procedure during install and manually install them after installing 13.04 by going to the update manager.

Comment: I am mid install right now from a disk. Sort of, it seems to have failed and stopped, but I am still in the install section of setup. I am only installing 13.04 to fix the update manager from 12.04. If I use a separate partition for 13.04, I will lose all my files from 12.04, which I would prefer to keep.

Comment: can u post a photo of exactly where are u stuck? still I would suggest backup up your data on an external drive and go for a clean install as if you update from existing 12.04 still some remnants would be left even after upgrading to 13.04.

Comment: How do I upload photos?

Comment: upload it any free photo sharing website and paste the link over here.

Comment: ![Screen](http://snag.gy/vv6Mn.jpg) I do not have enough points to post the image.

Comment: did the thing get sorted or you are still stuck. If yes just cancel the thing and download a fresh image and choose to upgrade in the options listed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to come back. Thank you for the advice. I quit, opened ubuntu as a temporary os, copied the home folder off, most of the files anyway, and completely reinstalled ubuntu.

Comment: ohkk that's good